# Install canvas on raspberry pi terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, node.js, docker

I tried run my code node.js, and report to developer and he told me "install canvas" on linux. I found and tried many solutions on internet but nothing work.

developer: "... i would suggest you to look at the issues of "installing canvas on linux" and instead of installing text on gif, first try installing canvas"

My "version" of SO is that:

[image]

Comment: It sounds you need a window manager and the supporting stuff.